# Positioning On Across Different Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser

When I create web page, I want all features on the page to be placed on the same position in different browsers. Sometimes some features are placed on different positions, when I run the page on different browsers.I am using these variables to determine what browser is being opened right know and with if statement for example I determine some options.

```
//var firefox = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1);
//var opera = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") != -1);
//var ie = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1);
//var safari = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1);
//var scrome = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1);
```

**1. Is it a good way to do like this when some features are placed on different positions in different browsers ?**

**2.What type is returned when I am using 'navigator.userAgent.indexOf(...)'. Is it boolean or some kind of collection which returns the position of the parameter, like the hashtable does ?. What type returns exactly ?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Different browsers may have different behavior of initial positions, a good practice to make them behaves same is to do CSS reset.
2. `navigator.userAgent` is a string object, thus `.indexOf(...)` returns integer `Number`

Comment: What do you mean abaout CSS reset ? Can you give me example. Should I use the code above ?

Comment: There are one million different reasons why two browsers might render the same page differently. I'm not sure if CSS reset is of great help.

Comment: For example, initially different browsers may set different margin for body element. So, to make consistent layout, you need handle differently for different browsers. A good solution is we first remove all browser default styles, then all the looks will be the same and we can add custom styles for all browsers. this is called CSS reset. An article shows more information http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/

Comment: Sure, if you want to do browser different actions as well as styling, a good choice is Modernizr: http://modernizr.com/

Comment: So I understand that I should create different css files for different browsers. I am right ?

Answer (score 0):

(1) don't do browser detection based on the user agent string. This is highly unreliable and very much not 2013. You want to use a framework like modernizr to detect which features are supported (and which are not). [This](http://modernizr.com/docs/) is a good start.

(2) Not a collection, just a number that describes the position of the searched string in the original string. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp), or find out yourself:

```
typeof(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("foo"))
```

(3) BTW: amazing name for posting beginner questions ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One more question, can I use the code above only for positioning for example margin and padding on some tag element ?

Comment: Please dont ask new questions in comments - rather update the original question.

Answer (score 0):

so you r looking for this i think :

```
  <!--[if IE]> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <!-->
```

that code should be place in the Head section of the page you could specify a multiple css page for each browser this link is for IE(internet explorer) for example